# Trying to set one value from another in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi everyone I have a problem I can't seem to get around, I am new to crystal so if I have missed something then please point it out. 
I am trying to achieve this. 
If a set of conditions are met then print a value if other conditions are met print a different value or else print main header. Below is what I have so far,

My problem is I can't seem to set the string to be correct.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
  booleanVar bPrintedRAD;
  booleanVar bPrintedGCS;
  booleanVar bPrintedHEAD;
  booleanVar bPrintedTHROM;
  booleanVar bPrintedWAR;
  booleanVar bPrintedPAP;
  booleanVar bPrintedSYM;

  if {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.CodeNum} = 5 then
    {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.OrderItemName};

   shared stringVar OrderItemNameQ:= {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.OrderItemName}; 



  If OrderItemNameQ = "CT Brain" 
   then

  if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "RAD Clinical Pathways"  
    //and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "Stroke"
    and instr ({CV3OrderUserData.Value},"Stroke")>0
    then bPrintedRAD := true;


  if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "CTBrain2gcs"
    and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedGCS := true;

 if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "ctbrain2headache"
   and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedHEAD := true;

if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "ctbrain2strokethrom"
  and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedTHROM := true;

if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "ctbrain2warfarin"
  and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedWAR := true;

if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "CTbrainpapillo"
  and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedPAP := true;

if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "ctbrainprogsym"
  and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedSYM := true;


if bPrintedRAD = true and (bPrintedGCS = true or bPrintedHEAD = true or   bPrintedTHROM = true or 
  bPrintedWAR = true or bPrintedPAP = true or bPrintedSYM = true)
   then OrderItemNameQ := "STROKE ONE HOUR"
 else 
 if bPrintedRAD = true and (bPrintedGCS = false and bPrintedHEAD = false and   bPrintedTHROM = false and
 bPrintedWAR = false and bPrintedPAP = false and bPrintedSYM = false)
   then OrderItemNameQ := "STROKE 24 HOURS"
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Hi, nope no error it just fails to display in a variable box. I have the {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.OrderItemName} displaying in a value output box above it so I can see what is being shown but I don't think the shared value is being given the output.

Comment: do you see any error in these lines ` if {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.CodeNum} = 5 then
    {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.OrderItemName};

   shared stringVar OrderItemNameQ:= {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.OrderItemName};` are you sure code got compuiled

Comment: When I put it into crystal and save it goes in fine with no errors

Comment: I have completely striped it all down to just this to see If I can get it to pass the value

Comment: do one thing after code just give `;` and print `OrderItemNameQ ` at the end and see output

Comment: Shared stringVar OrderItemNameQ;
stringVar OrderItemNameQ:="";
OrderItemNameQ = {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.OrderItemName};

if OrderItemNameQ = "CT Brain"
then "This is right" 
else 
{IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.OrderItemName};

Comment: In the variable box I get CT Brain and not the This is right

Comment: You have missed colon in `OrderItemNameQ = {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.OrderItemName}`

Answer (score 0):

I think your formula is correct but haven't correctly closed the blocks. try this:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
  booleanVar bPrintedRAD;
  booleanVar bPrintedGCS;
  booleanVar bPrintedHEAD;
  booleanVar bPrintedTHROM;
  booleanVar bPrintedWAR;
  booleanVar bPrintedPAP;
  booleanVar bPrintedSYM;
shared stringVar OrderItemNameQ;

  if {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.CodeNum} = 5 then
       OrderItemNameQ:= {IS_DHFT_Aide_Memoir.OrderItemName}; 



  If OrderItemNameQ = "CT Brain" 
   then
(
  if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "RAD Clinical Pathways"  
    //and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "Stroke"
    and instr ({CV3OrderUserData.Value},"Stroke")>0
    then bPrintedRAD := true;


  if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "CTBrain2gcs"
    and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedGCS := true;

 if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "ctbrain2headache"
   and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedHEAD := true;

if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "ctbrain2strokethrom"
  and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedTHROM := true;

if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "ctbrain2warfarin"
  and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedWAR := true;

if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "CTbrainpapillo"
  and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedPAP := true;

if {CV3OrderUserData.UserDataCode} = "ctbrainprogsym"
  and {CV3OrderUserData.Value} = "1" then bPrintedSYM := true;
)

if bPrintedRAD = true and (bPrintedGCS = true or bPrintedHEAD = true or   bPrintedTHROM = true or 
  bPrintedWAR = true or bPrintedPAP = true or bPrintedSYM = true)
   then OrderItemNameQ := "STROKE ONE HOUR"
 else 
 if bPrintedRAD = true and (bPrintedGCS = false and bPrintedHEAD = false and   bPrintedTHROM = false and
 bPrintedWAR = false and bPrintedPAP = false and bPrintedSYM = false)
   then OrderItemNameQ := "STROKE 24 HOURS";
OrderItemNameQ;
```